# php pecl install mac os x 10.6

Tags: php, pecl

Does anyone know how to install pecl for mac os x 10.6. I have tried googling with no luck.

Comment: this possibly should be a superuser question, what pecl plugin you trying to install because it may be available via macports?

Comment: Good question. Trying to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

PECL should ship with PHP on OSX 10.6. If not, it may be a part if the development libraries packaged with OSX's install disc. You can identify if it's installed by typing the following in your Terminal.app (should return a path).

```bash
which pecl
```

### If your unable to find PECL

Sometimes it's easier to re-install PHP. Look into [macports](http://www.macports.org/), or [homebrew](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php). Both package managers ship the latest PHP5 (including PECL).

### Verify PECL is working

Updated your local database with the latest packages, and install a simple package (like [bbcode](http://pecl.php.net/package/bbcode).)

```bash
sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
sudo pecl install bbcode
```

### Install a PECL package without PECL

This is hit-n-miss depending on the package. To install a PECL package manully, you would follow the traditional `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` process.

```bash
# Download the package
curl -O http://pecl.php.net/get/bbcode-1.0.3b1.tgz
# Extract archive
tar zvxf bbcode-1.0.3b1.tgz
# Change directory
cd bbcode-1.0.3b1
# Apply local php settings
phpize
# Run configuration script
./configure
# Compile
make
# Verify build
make test
# Install on system
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward method if you don't want to go through brew is install directly from the pear website.

`$ curl -O https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar`

for more configurations see [the pear website](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php)